# SQL query in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having a hard time totaling my two averages at the bottom of my results. I've tried using a rollup and a union with no success.  Any help will be greatly appreciated.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
SUPPLIER_ID SUPPLIER    SUPPLIER_TYPE   AVG_LISTINGS    AVG_PORTAL_LISTINGS
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
493         Advanced    Vendor Feed     293             0
314         Advanced    Vendor Feed     902             768
3243        Aiken       BOR/AOR/MLS     141             0
                                        1336            768
```

Query:

```
SELECT    
          slc.fk_supplier_id SUPPLIER_ID,
          '"'||oms.internal_name||'"' AS SUPPLIER,
          omst.description AS SUPPLIER_TYPE, 
          ROUND(AVG(slc.for_rent_list_count)) AS  AVG_LISTINGS,
          ROUND(AVG(slc.for_rent_portal_count)) AS AVG_PORTAL_LISTINGS
 FROM    stats_listing_counts slc
    JOIN ols_mls_supplier oms ON oms.pk_supplier_id = slc.fk_supplier_id
    LEFT JOIN ols_mls_supplier_types omst ON omst.pk_suppliertype = oms.fk_suppliertype
WHERE slc.stat_date >= '02-NOV-13'
  AND for_rent_list_count > 0
GROUP BY slc.fk_supplier_id,oms.internal_name,omst.description 
ORDER BY internal_name ASC;
```

Comment: Do you really want the sum of the averages, or the average of all records?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT
SUPPLIER_ID,
SUPPLIER,
SUPPLIER_TYPE,
ROUND(AVG(slc.for_rent_list_count)) AS  AVG_LISTINGS,
ROUND(AVG(slc.for_rent_portal_count)) AS AVG_PORTAL_LISTINGS
FROM 
(
  SELECT    
  slc.fk_supplier_id SUPPLIER_ID,
  '"'||oms.internal_name||'"' AS SUPPLIER,
  omst.description AS SUPPLIER_TYPE, 
  slc.for_rent_list_count,
  slc.for_rent_portal_count  
  FROM stats_listing_counts slc
  JOIN ols_mls_supplier oms ON oms.pk_supplier_id = slc.fk_supplier_id
  LEFT JOIN ols_mls_supplier_types omst ON omst.pk_suppliertype = oms.fk_suppliertype
  WHERE slc.stat_date >= '02-NOV-13' AND for_rent_list_count > 0
) 
GROUP BY ROULLUP((SUPPLIER_ID,SUPPLIER,SUPPLIER_TYPE))
ORDER BY internal_name ASC;
```